# React Native Expo WebView Communication

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, expo

I'm working on an app where I need to interact with a webview. Essentially I need to call a function in the webview and capture (somehow) what it returns.

Essentially the parent class has a button. This buttons triggers a function  called in the child class which sends a message to the webview. The webview then sends a message back which triggers the `onMessage()` function. So my question basically is, **How can the parent function `testFunc()` access the data the webview returned.**

Here is a simplified example of the child class.

```
export default class Child extends Component {
  sendMessageToWebView = () => {
    this.webview.postMessage("Hello WebView, from React Native");
  }

  html = () => {
    `<body>
     <script>
       document.addEventListener("message", function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         window.postMessage("Hello from WebView :)");
       });
     </script>
    </body>`
  }

  onMessage = (data) => {
    console.log(data.nativeEvent.data);
    return data.nativeEvent.data;
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <WebView
          ref={(view) => { this.webview = view; }}
          source={{ html() }}
          onMessage={this.onMessage}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the parent class

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  testFunc = () => {
    this.child.sendMessageToWebView();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <Button onPress={this.testFunc} title={'Test'} />
         <Child ref={child => {this.child = child}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I have thought about using states, but I end up with a similar problem. How does the parent function know when the state has been changed in the child class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the state in the child class after the data has been received. We can then call a function `sendData` in the parent to update the state of that parent class with the new data.

```
export default class Child extends Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

  ...

  onMessage = (data) => {
    const data = data.nativeEvent.data;
    this.setState({ data: data }, sendToParent);
  }

  sendToParent = () => {
    this.props.sendData(this.state.data);
  }
  ...
```

You can then access the state of the child class from the parent class `this.state.data`

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

 ...

 sendData = (data) => {
   this.setState({ data: data });
 }

 ...

}
```

Comment: Great work! At work I'll typically code super readable, but if I'm working on personal projects I'll do something like:

`sendData = data => this.setState({ data });`